# Angular tips to skip polyfills in case of a fixed target (Chrome 67)

Tags: angular, typescript, polyfills, tsconfig

I'm working on an Angular 6 project.

My target is really specific (Chrome 67), so are there any tips in order to exclude all the possible polyfills needed to other target browsers?

- Could I switch my target prop in the tsconfig file to es6 ?
- Could I remove the core-js library from my dependencies?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My target is really specific (Chrome 67), so are there any tips in order to exclude all the possible polyfills needed to other target browsers?

If you are *only* using chrome 67 you can set `target: es6` and remove the dependency on `core-js`.

Answer (score 0):

> Could I switch my target prop in the tsconfig file to es6 ?

Yes.

> Could I remove the core-js library from my dependencies?

I believe this library is only imported by the `polyfills.ts` file. If you comment out all the lines in `polyfill.ts` there is no need to remove it from `package.json`. WebPack will not include the library unless it is referenced.

Comment: So far I have the default polyfill.ts content, with only the following imports:
import 'core-js/es7/reflect';
import 'zone.js/dist/zone';  // Included with Angular CLI.